# R - optimal way to truncate with dplyr

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, truncate, quantile

I'm using R and ggplot to visualise variable distributions. But most of the time, because of some extrem values, I have to truncate the variable to generate a better visualisation. For instance:

```
library(tidyverse)

data.frame(x = c(runif(500, min = 0, max = 1), 1e3)) %>%
  ggplot() + geom_density(aes(x = x))
```

[image]

I use the base functions `quantile()` and `ifelse()` to truncate and get a better visualisation. But I don't feel it is optimal, the function quantile() is repeted, meaning it's calculated twice. Does someone now a more optimal way? (without saving the quantile in a previous step)

```
data.frame(x = c(runif(500, min = 0, max = 1), 1e3)) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(x), list(~ ifelse(. > quantile(., .99), quantile(., .99), .))) %>% 
  ggplot() + geom_density(aes(x = x))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
data.frame(x = c(runif(500, min = 0, max = 1), 1e3)) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(x), list(~ pmin(., quantile(., .99)))) %>% 
  ggplot() + geom_density(aes(x = x))
```

`pmin` does vector-wise mins, ala

```r
x <- sample(10)
x
#  [1] 10  9  6  4  5  3  2  1  7  8
pmin(x, 5)
#  [1] 5 5 5 4 5 3 2 1 5 5
```

And you only calculate the quantile once.

FYI, `mutate_at` has been [*superseded*](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate_all.html) by the use of `across`.

```r
data.frame(x = c(runif(500, min = 0, max = 1), 1e3)) %>%
  mutate(across(x, ~ pmin(., quantile(., .99)))) %>% 
  ggplot() + geom_density(aes(x = x))
```

Note that the `list(~ quantile(., 0.99))` method is still supported, but when a `list`, the naming convention is different. Compare:

```r
set.seed(42)
x <- data.frame(x = c(runif(500, min = 0, max = 1), 1e3))
x %>%
  mutate(across(x, list(~ pmin(., quantile(., .99))))) %>%
  head(.)
#           x       x_1
# 1 0.9148060 0.9148060
# 2 0.9370754 0.9370754
# 3 0.2861395 0.2861395
# 4 0.8304476 0.8304476
# 5 0.6417455 0.6417455
# 6 0.5190959 0.5190959
x %>%
  mutate(across(x, ~ pmin(., quantile(., .99)))) %>%
  head(.)
#           x
# 1 0.9148060
# 2 0.9370754
# 3 0.2861395
# 4 0.8304476
# 5 0.6417455
# 6 0.5190959
```

(where the `list` method produces a new column named `x_1`, but `ggplot2` is still looking at the untruncated `x`).

Answer (score 1):

The statistician I worked with always promoted the **Winsorizing** function. Where extreme values are replaced by less extreme values.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winsorizing

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DescTools/versions/0.99.39/topics/Winsorize

```
library(DescTools)
data.frame(x = c(runif(500, min = 0, max = 1), 1e3)) %>%
  mutate(x = DescTools::Winsorize(x, probs = c(0, 0.99))) %>% 
  ggplot() + geom_density(aes(x = x))
```

Extracted function from DescTools for a light weight user defined function:

```
Winsorize <- function(x, minval = NULL, maxval = NULL,
                      probs=c(0.05, 0.95), na.rm = FALSE, type=7) {
    
  if(is.null(minval) || is.null(maxval)){
    xq <- quantile(x=x, probs=probs, na.rm=na.rm, type=type)
    if(is.null(minval)) minval <- xq[1L]
    if(is.null(maxval)) maxval <- xq[2L]
  }
 
  x[xmaxval] <- maxval
 
  return(x)
}
```

SOURCE - https://github.com/AndriSignorell/DescTools/blob/master/R/DescTools.r

Comment: I think the function is fine, working effectively the same as `pmin`, though their indexed-replacement alleges to be faster. I'd argue, though, that pulling in that package (with its requirements and compilation) for the use of that function might be overkill for some projects, esp if it's being distributed. It might be a good option to mimic the functionality of that `function` by making a UDF with its 8 lines of code. Nice suggestion.

Comment: I looked at the code, and you are correct, a user defined function would be a lighter solution, versus installing DescTools. And ultimately winsorizing is using quantile under the hood.